# Sorting an array object with lodash along with date

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lodash

Here I am trying to sort the `priority_level` such that first the alphabet comes and then number, Also along with that I am trying to sort `priority_date` such that oldest first along with `priority_date` but still it has to show the Alphabet first
example result I expect :

```
            priority level: P Date: 1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z
            priority level: C Date: 2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z
            priority level: 1 Date: 2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z
            priority level: 1 Date: 2014-09-03T00:00:00.000Z
            priority level: 5 Date: 2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z
```

[Here Like for same level `1` it should show the old date first like above.]
 Below is the object array I am getting, and want to perfrom this entire logic operation on this.
            I am using lodash orderby but not sure it it helps with this

```
   const input =   [{
        priority_level: 'P ',
        comments: '',
        withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
        condition: '',
        _id: 5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d44,
        company: 5db00a135399ab5cad9e0049,
        priority_date: 1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z,
        registration_type: 5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4b,
        sequence: 6835,
        waiver_request: false,
        waiver_granted: false,
        waiver_letter_date: null,
        letter_date: null,
        waiver_sent: null,
        no_extention_letter: false,
        mpaa_extention_granted: false
      },
      {
        priority_level: '1 ',
        comments: '',
        withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
        condition: '',
        _id: 5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d43,
        company: 5db00a145399ab5cad9e0096,
        priority_date: 2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z,
        registration_type: 5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a,
        sequence: 13505,
        waiver_request: false,
        waiver_granted: false,
        waiver_letter_date: null,
        letter_date: null,
        waiver_sent: null,
        no_extention_letter: false,
        mpaa_extention_granted: false
      },
      {
        priority_level: 'C ',
        comments: '',
        withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
        condition: '',
        _id: 5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d42,
        company: 5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5c,
        priority_date: 2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z,
        registration_type: 5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a,
        sequence: 13506,
        waiver_request: false,
        waiver_granted: false,
        waiver_letter_date: null,
        letter_date: null,
        waiver_sent: null,
        no_extention_letter: false,
        mpaa_extention_granted: false
      },
      {
        priority_level: '5 ',
        comments: '',
        withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
        condition: '',
        _id: 5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d41,
        company: 5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5a,
        priority_date: 2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z,
        registration_type: 5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a,
        sequence: 13508,
        waiver_request: false,
        waiver_granted: false,
        waiver_letter_date: null,
        letter_date: null,
        waiver_sent: null,
        no_extention_letter: false,
        mpaa_extention_granted: false
      },

{
            priority_level: '1 ',
            comments: '',
            withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
            condition: '',
            _id: 5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d41,
            company: 5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5a,
            priority_date: 2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z,
            registration_type: 5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a,
            sequence: 13508,
            waiver_request: false,
            waiver_granted: false,
            waiver_letter_date: null,
            letter_date: null,
            waiver_sent: null,
            no_extention_letter: false,
            mpaa_extention_granted: false
          }]



    const result = input.sort((a, b) => {

      const aNumericPriorityLevel = Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(a.priority_level));
      const bNumericPriorityLevel = Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(b.priority_level));

      // If one items has letter priority level, and the other does not, sort
      // a/b pair based on if a or b was the number
      if (aNumericPriorityLevel !== bNumericPriorityLevel) {
        return aNumericPriorityLevel ? 1 : -1;
      }

      // If a/b pair are both number or both letter, then sort in descending
      // order based on date
      return Date.parse(a.priority_date) - Date.parse(b.priority_date);
    });

    console.log(result)
```

The above works fine, but do not refine date with same priority_level, it messed up with that senario.
Like want to sort normally with alphabet and numeric works fine but date logic will be like if data is same then it should arrange by descending date.
Here if I want numbers sorting like 1,2,3,3,4,5 and so on but if any number has 2 entires like 1,2,2,3,3,3,1 then it should be be kept as date descending date entry for numeric which has more than one entries.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be as follows:

```js
// I've stripped out the extra data to give the answer more clarity
const input = [{
    priority_level: 'P ',
    priority_date: "1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    priority_level: '1 ',
    priority_date: "2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    priority_level: '1 ',
    priority_date: '1985-02-15T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    priority_level: 'C ',
    priority_date: "2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    priority_level: '5 ',
    priority_date: "2005-02-15T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]

const result = input.sort((a, b) => {

  const aNumericPriorityLevel = Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(a.priority_level));
  const bNumericPriorityLevel = Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(b.priority_level));

  // If one items has letter priority level, and the other does not, sort
  // a/b pair based on if a or b was the number
  if (aNumericPriorityLevel !== bNumericPriorityLevel) {
    return aNumericPriorityLevel ? 1 : -1;
  }
  else if(aNumericPriorityLevel === true) {
    return bNumericPriorityLevel - aNumericPriorityLevel;
  }

  // If a/b pair are both number or both letter, then sort in descending
  // order based on date
  return Date.parse(b.priority_date) - Date.parse(a.priority_date);
});

console.log(result)
```

Here, [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is used with a custom callback that sorts input pairs based on two criteria:

- The primary sort criteria depends on the value(s) of `priority_level` 
  on each input object `a` and `b`. If only one value is parsable as an integer, then we give prescendnce to this as a sorting crteria, and return a sorting direction for this pair based on which item had a the numeric string value for the `priority_level` field.
- Otherwise, if both `a` and `b` have numeric (or non-numeric) string values for `priority_level`, then the pair is sorted based on their `priority_date` values. Here, the [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method can be used to convert your date strings to integers, and the difference of the parsed integers are used to direct the sorting

Hope that helps!

Comment: Here if I want numbers sorting like 1,2,3,3,4,5 and so on but if any number has 2 entires like 1,2,2,3,3,3,1 then it should be be kept as date descending date entry for numeric which has more than one entries.

Comment: Like want to sort normally with alphabet and numeric works fine but date logic will be like if data is same then it should arrange by descending date.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, that you want the items to be sorted in descending order for dates? I've just updated the code snippet - does that match your requirements?

Comment: Can you check the updated question? i've mentioned the new string and exprected result

Comment: Thanks - I updated the answer based on the new information, does that work as required? Here is "letters" are paired, the items will decsend by date. If "numbers" are paired, the items are sorted by decsending date. If a "number" and "letter" are paired, the letter item will come first. Does that describe the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look as below:

```js
const dataObj = [{
      priority_level: 'P ',
      comments: '',
      withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
      condition: '',
      _id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d44',
      company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9e0049',
      priority_date: '1980-02-08T00:00:00.000Z',
      registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4b',
      sequence: 6835,
      waiver_request: false,
      waiver_granted: false,
      waiver_letter_date: null,
      letter_date: null,
      waiver_sent: null,
      no_extention_letter: false,
      mpaa_extention_granted: false,
    },
    {
      priority_level: '1 ',
      comments: '',
      withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
      condition: '',
      _id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d43',
      company: '5db00a145399ab5cad9e0096',
      priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z',
      registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
      sequence: 13505,
      waiver_request: false,
      waiver_granted: false,
      waiver_letter_date: null,
      letter_date: null,
      waiver_sent: null,
      no_extention_letter: false,
      mpaa_extention_granted: false,
    },
    {
      priority_level: 'C ',
      comments: '',
      withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
      condition: '',
      _id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d42',
      company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5c',
      priority_date: '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000Z',
      registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
      sequence: 13506,
      waiver_request: false,
      waiver_granted: false,
      waiver_letter_date: null,
      letter_date: null,
      waiver_sent: null,
      no_extention_letter: false,
      mpaa_extention_granted: false,
    },
    {
      priority_level: '5 ',
      comments: '',
      withdraw_granted_conditions: 'false',
      condition: '',
      _id: '5db00ad95399ab5cad9e6d41',
      company: '5db00a135399ab5cad9dff5a',
      priority_date: '1985-02-15T00:00:00.000Z',
      registration_type: '5db00a125399ab5cad9dfe4a',
      sequence: 13508,
      waiver_request: false,
      waiver_granted: false,
      waiver_letter_date: null,
      letter_date: null,
      waiver_sent: null,
      no_extention_letter: false,
      mpaa_extention_granted: false,
    }];
    const getAlphabet = [];
    const getNumber = [];
    const alphabetCheck = /^[a-zA-Z]/g;
    dataObj.map((item) => {
      if (item.priority_level.match(alphabetCheck)) {
        return getAlphabet.push(
          { priority_level: item.priority_level, priority_date: item.priority_date }
        );
      }
      return getNumber.push(
        { priority_level: item.priority_level, priority_date: item.priority_date }
      );
    });
    const getSortedAlphabet = getAlphabet.sort((a, b) => ((a.priority_date > b.priority_date) ? 1 : ((b.priority_date > a.priority_date) ? -1 : 0)));
    const getSortedDate = getNumber.sort((a, b) => ((a.priority_date > b.priority_date) ? 1 : ((b.priority_date > a.priority_date) ? -1 : 0)));
    const tempCombine = [...getSortedAlphabet, ...getSortedDate];
    console.log('tempCombine', tempCombine);
```

Comment: do you mean that priority_level has the same value as 1,2,2,3,3,3,1?